# Rails pool of background jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, job-scheduling

I'm writting webtool using Ruby+Rails. I decided to ask about already existing solution before inventing mine.

`Task:` I need a pool of background jobs, that will run periodicaly (user sets his interval). There are plenty solutions like Resque or Sidekiq, but they provide "one-time" jobs. User can create new task, that gets into "pool".

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution might be to use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to enqueue background jobs.

Another option might be to use an extension to Sidekiq that handles periodical jobs: [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused about how to implement my task. I feel like I need to separate my background processing, but don't know how to do it right - some separated server, engine for Rails, or just  process that communicates with Rails through soket? Any info source will be great.

Comment: Hard to tell if you do not share your code nor tell anything about your technology stack. Assuming that you decided to use Sidekiq, then the [Sidekiw homepage and documentation](http://sidekiq.org/) might be a good starting point.

Comment: The case that I'm trying to build my stack) Am open to proposition, as I have minor experience with Ruby. 
My thoughts was to make `list of jobs & pool of supervisors`, that checks this list and schedules job + `resque` or `sidekiq` for background processing + `WebSocket` to update my web dashboarf